# What's wrong with this Razor code?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

```
@using System.Configuration
@using UI.AuctionService
@using UI.Common
@using UI.Helpers

@model UI.Models.AuctionFrontendListViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Auction List";
}

<h2>@Model.Title</h2>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Image
        </th>
        <th>
            Type
        </th>
        <th>
            Auction title
        </th>
        <th>
            Starts
        </th>
        <th>
            Ends
        </th>
        <th>
            Is featured
        </th>
        <th>
            Bid count
        </th>
        <th>
            Creation time
        </th>
        <th></th>   
    </tr>

@foreach (var auction in Model.Auctions)
{
    var type = string.Empty;
    if (auction.Auction is LubAuction)
    {
        type = "Lowest unique wins";
    }
    else if (auction.Auction is EsfAuction)
    {
        type = "Highest wins";
    }

    string imagesFolderPath = HttpContextHelper.GetPathInServer(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImagesFolderPath"]);
    string itemImagesFolderPath = Path.Combine(imagesFolderPath, ImageType.Item + @"\\" + auction.Auction.InventoryReference);
    string chosenImage = string.Empty;
    if (Directory.Exists(itemImagesFolderPath))
    {
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(itemImagesFolderPath);
        if (files.Length > 0)
        {
            chosenImage = files[0];
        }
    }

    <tr>
       <td>
            <img src="@chosenImage" />
       </td>
       <td>
            @type
       </td>
       <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => auction.Auction.Title)
        </td>
        <td>
            @DateTimeHelper.LocalDateTime(auction.Auction.Starts)
        </td>
        <td>
            @DateTimeHelper.LocalDateTime(auction.Auction.Ends)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => auction.Auction.IsFeatured)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => auction.Auction.BidCount)
        </td>
        <td>
            @DateTimeHelper.LocalDateTime(auction.Auction.AddedDate)
        </td>
        <td>
           @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = auction.Auction.Id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
<div class="pager">
@Html.PageLinks(Model.PagingInfo, x => Url.Action(Model.Action, new { page = x }))
</div>
```

Comment: Please narrow down your question a little bit - what specific part is giving you problems?

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: Well, the issue is that I can't get the image in the img tag to display.

Comment: Have you looked at the rendered output ("view source" in your browser) to see if the html is being rendered as you expect?

Comment: I would guess that the chosenImage string is never getting set, then. Apparently your code that finds the image in the directory is faulty.

Comment: You certainly got an error message. Would you mind sharing it with us?

Comment: OMG we're back to classic ASP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the image is the issue, I would suggest doing this differently. Your Razor view probably shouldn't be in charge of scouring the server to look for images; consider pushing that info into the view through the model or ViewData.

In addition, why are you passing in `@"\\"` to Path.Combine? You're adding a double-slash to the path. Let Path.Combine handle this instead. I think that's probably your main problem. Do one of the following:

```
string itemImagesFolderPath = Path.Combine(imagesFolderPath, ImageType.Item + @"\" + auction.Auction.InventoryReference);
```

or, more preferably

```
string itemImagesFolderPath = Path.Combine(imagesFolderPath, ImageType.Item, auction.Auction.InventoryReference);
```